# Serialization in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, windows-phone-7.1

I'm writting a program in .Net for Windows Phone 7.

I have a part code:

```
public void deSerialize()
    {
        sr = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, myFile));
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Stream strm = File.OpenRead("Data\\myFile.txt");
        menetrend = serializer.ReadObject(strm) as RootObject;
    }
```

My problem is in here:

Stream strm = File.OpenRead("Data\myFile.txt");

The complier cannot see the myFile.txt and I don't know how can I solve the problem.

Comment: It seems to me that the first line of your code already shows you how to open that `Stream`...?

Comment: This is a wrong code, this revised code section:
using ( Stream strm = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data\\myFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, myFile)) menetrend = serializer.ReadObject(strm) as RootObject;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I would definitely look into is it looks like you are trying to open up too streams one via  `File` and one using `IsolatedStorageStream`.  As @PhilBolduc said you need to use `IsolatedStorageStream`.  I would also like to make a suggestion and use `using` statements when accesing streams so they dispose of themselves.

```
    using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, storage))
    {
    }
```

Comment: Okey, I understand, I use this:
using ( Stream strm = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data\\myFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, myFile))
                menetrend = serializer.ReadObject(strm) as RootObject;     But this isn't good, because the FileMode shoud be Read. And I don't know how to use.

Comment: Thanks the answer, the code is good.
public void deSerialize()
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
            using ( Stream strm = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data\\myFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, myFile))
                menetrend = serializer.ReadObject(strm) as RootObject;
        }

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the IsolatedStorageFileStream.  You cannot read the file directly.

Comment: I understand and know it. But how to write the code? I re-writed the code, here:
using ( Stream strm = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data\\myFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, myFile))
                menetrend = serializer.ReadObject(strm) as RootObject;